# How to get token from sessionStorage in node before serving react static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, passport.js

I have created a login page which is a react webpage. The purpose of the page is to login a user. If the user is successfully logged in using a user id and a password, a jwt token is returned by the server to the login page. The current login pages saves the returned jwt to sessionStorage. I have used passport.js with jwt authentication method.

I have an admin page. I want that page to be viewed only if the user is authenticated. This is another react web app which is separate from the one above.  I want the react static files for admin area to be served only if a user is authenticated or logged in first.

Now my problem is how do I send the token from session storage on the client side to the server side. Session storage can not be accessed by the server side.
I want to reiterate my login page and admin page are separate react components.

Here is my server side code: -

```
app.get('/admin', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false, failureRedirect: '/login'}),(req, res) => {
    //Send admin static files 
    ....
})
```

My login: -

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

    //Add sanitization function later
    const userID = req.body.user;
    const password = req.body.password;

    //check if user credentials are correct, then return json token
    if (verifyCredentials(userID, password)){
        let token = generateJSONToken(userID);
        res.json({id: userID, token}).status(200);
    } else {
        res.json({error: "Wrong username or password"})
    }
})
```

My login page: -

```
const LoginArea = () => {

    const loginInput = useRef();
    const passwordInput = useRef();

    //shows error message
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

    //Submit login form to the server
    const submitLogin = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const loginResult = await login(loginInput.current.value, passwordInput.current.value);

        if (loginResult.data.error){
            setErrorMessage(loginResult.data.error);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setErrorMessage("");
            }, 5000);
        }

        if (loginResult.data.token){
            storeTokenOnUserside(loginResult.data.token)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Box>
                {errorMessage}
                <FormControl isRequired>
                    <FormLabel>Login Id:</FormLabel>
                    <Input ref={loginInput} type="text" placeholder="Login ID"/>
                </FormControl>
                
                <FormControl isRequired >
                    <FormLabel>Password:</FormLabel>
                    <Input ref={passwordInput} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </FormControl>
               
                <FormControl isRequired>
                    <Button type="submit" onClick={(e) => submitLogin(e)}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </FormControl>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginArea;
```

Comment: It is _strongly_ encouraged not to store your auth related JWTs on the client to prevent XSS attacks and instead store them in an HTTP-Only cookie which the frontend can't access directly.

Comment: I understand. This is for educational and learning purposes.